# Azure Resource Manager REST API - Encrypted at rest?

Tags: encryption, azure-resource-manager

Does Azure Resource Manager REST API (https://management.azure.com) support encryption at rest, i.e. data stored in the API back-end is encrypted?

I understand that requests made to, and responses received from the API are secured via SSL. So, the data transmitted should be encrypted in transit.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. Nobody encrypts incoming REST requests.

If you are talking about Azure storage - that has encryption at rest feature.
Data Lake Supports has that as well, Azure SQL has, CosmosDB has.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-encryption
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-encryption-at-rest

Comment: By incoming REST requests, do you mean "on the wire" or in memory after having received the request? And my question is to whether ARM uses a backed that is encrypted at REST.

Comment: why would you encrypt the request. it makes no sense. you get it, you process it and that's it. if you are asking a question about how azure backend is secured, i wouldnt be able to give you a definitive answer, but given that Microsoft aims at enterprise and government customers I'm pretty sure everything is encrypted

Comment: hey @4c74356b41 can you remove your downvote? I want to know that when I am sending my information to an API, it is encrypting my data when storing it.